# I can't redirect /domain.com/.html to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Search Console Error is showing me this URL:

/domain.com/.html as an error.

If I put that url in my browser I get:
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /.html on this server.

this situation is because Apache is searching a file named .html how can I add a rule for htaccess file to fix this situation? if the URL is /.html redirect to index /

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning,

why exactly do you want /.html to be a valid call? Shouldn't it be /specificName.html like /stack.html?

Anyway, try something like this:

```
RewriteRule /(specificName)\.html$ / [R=permanent,L]
```

If you really meant /.html just leave the bracket out.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hello Thanks for your answer. I found the error was in sitemap.xml file. I removed the wrong url. Thanks